# Matlab - How can I plot a function for different inputs using for loop?

Tags: matlab

Trying to plot a function 2 times(once with x1,x2 = -2,2 , second with x1,x2 = -1,2) with the code below;however, only the second plot shows:

```
% We set the domain to [x1,x2];
x1 = [-2,-1]
x2 = [2,2]

% We plot the graphs
for i = 1:length(x1)
    [domain,range,plot] = vector(x1(i),x2(i))
end

function [x,y,fplot] = vector(a,b)
    x = [linspace(a,b)]
    f = @(x) x.^2
    y = f(x)
    fplot = plot(x,y)
end
```

Comment: unless you make a new figure, or tell MATLAB to `hold on`, it will replace the previous plot

Comment: Why do create a function and directly call it instead of simply `y = x.^2`?

Comment: @AnderBiguri, thanks, adding `figure` in the loop works. @ThomasSablik, didn't know that, it clears some space, thank you